# Узнать какой клиент отключился

Tags: сокет

Здравствуйте. Делаю на Qt клиент-сервер. Храню сокеты на сервере в QMap<int, QTcpSocket*> - дескриптор сокета в качестве ключа и указатель на сам сокет.
Проблема: по событию disconnect() сокет уже разъединен и дексриптор равен -1. Как мне удалять из QMap?

Comment: а, вы дескриптор в качестве ключа используете!

Comment: @asianirish, Про собственный класс я не подумал, а это уже решение.

Comment: А зачем [при таком количестве методов QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket-members.html) Вам вообще дескриптор понадобился?

Comment: @avp, нет оператора сравнения.  А как вы предложите хранить все сокеты?

Comment: Да я просто на Си пишу. 

Там проблем с чужими и до конца не известно как работающими структурами просто не возникает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тогда может отдельный класс создать - сокет+первоначальное положение дескриптора и хранить мэп указателей этого класса, потом дескриптор если обнулился (отминусодинусился), в члене этого класса останется. Или изобрести что-нибудь более изящное с помощью сигналов/слотов

---

Другое решение (после раздумий) - можно вообще отказаться от хранения сокетов (в мепе или любом контейнере), а обойтись только сигналами/слотами для управления. Я вспомнил, я тоже имел такой опыт, сначала сделал у нодов подноды и хранил их в мепе, а потом все перевел на отклик на сигналы, и оказалось, действительно, хранить ссылки к ним было ни к чему. ИМХО это рудементальное мышление "до-кьютишного" программиста в КьюТи :)